# How to extract the private exponent from PKCS#8 format in Java?

Tags: java, rsa, pkcs#8

I have a 2048 bit RSAPrivateKey in PKCS#8 format. I would like to flip single bits of the private exponent so that bruteforce becomes necessary.

This is how I create the key pair:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
```

In order to flip bits I convert the key into a Java.util.BitSet:

`BitSet priv = BitSet.valueOf(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());`

The outcoming BitSet has got `priv.size()` = 9792 Bits (sometimes it differs a little bit). I need to know which of the containing bits (probably 2048) represent the private secret. I've tried to find out its structure by looking at [RFC5208](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt) but I can't find any bit related information. I've also tried to compare the private exponent `rsaPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent()` with the entire private key `new BigInteger(rsaPrivateKey.getEncoded())` but could not find any similarities.

However, as I start flipping random bits either the decryption works anyhow or I get BadPaddingExceptions. To my way of thinking decryption might work with flipped bits but results in wrong decrypted plaintexts. Which bits do I have to flip to achieve this? Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: You shouldnt try to improve algorithms you dont understand. Use 4096 bit keys and get hold of a copy of Schneiers book on crypthography.

Comment: I don't want to improve the algorithm and key length is incidental. The purpose is a brute force experiment and therefore I need to flip some bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gather what you want to do is take an existing RSA private key, mess around with the private exponent, and take the result and make it back into an RSA private key for further experiments. I would not use the getEncoded() method because the encoded object is the DER encoding of complex ASN.1 structure and you don't want to parse that to find your way to the private exponent. A better way is to extract the private exponent directly as a BigInteger.

Here is one example of how to do this to flip the 29th bit. Obviously you can tailor this to meet your needs.

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        BigInteger d = rsaPrivateKey.getPrivateExponent();

        // Flip some bits in d

        BigInteger newD = d.flipBit(29);

        // Make a new RSA private key with the modified private exponent

        RSAPrivateKeySpec newRSAPrivateSpec = new RSAPrivateKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey.getModulus(), newD);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPrivateKey newPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(newRSAPrivateSpec);
```

One thing to keep in mind: when you modify just the private exponent, the public exponent is no longer correct -- in fact the private exponent may also be invalid. If you want a *valid* RSA keypair you'll have to verify that the new private exponent d satisfies GCD(d, phi(n)) = 1, where phi(n) = (p-1) * (q-1) and p and q are the two prime factors of your RSA modulus, and then compute the new public exponent e=d<sup>-1</sup> mod phi(n).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found out that the private exponent is located in the RSAPrivateKey BitSet between bit 2424 and 4471. But this is a much better way and easy to handle.

Comment: How may I do it if my keypair is of the kind ECDSA? The `getPrivateExponent()` method is not available for the `PrivateKey` object.